# How to use jetpack compose in Android TV with remote control?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

how to use jetpack compose in android tv? The graphics are displayed normally, but the remote control cannot be used.

Comment: Have you tried setting `focusable()` modifier as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66652181/6835732)?

Comment: `focusable()` doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: You can check out [jetpack compose for tv packages](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/tv) which makes it simpler to use Jetpack Compose to build TV applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Modifier.focusable()` – that should do the trick.